# CSS of component balise doesn't load inside spefic component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js

I've a problem to load the css of my bloc component.

The webpage component allow to create an iframe and set some content inside easily.

It load correctly the template and script tag but not the css (it doesn't load).

Sometime it works, most of the time, it didn't.

I was thinking that it was a problem with the loading of the component but no.

If I load the component before or after the render of my "webpage" component : it don't load.

I've try with the auto import to true and after to false, but it solve nothing.

I have 2 components : webpage and bloc.

***bloc.vue***

```
<template>
  <div class="bloc">
    <p>Le texte</p>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
.bloc {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 20px;
}
</style>
```

***webpage.vue***

```
<script>
import Vue from "vue";
export default {
  props: {
    css: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      load: false,
    };
  },
  render(h) {
    return h("iframe", {
      on: { load: this.renderChildren },
    });
  },
  beforeUpdate() {
    //freezing to prevent unnessessary Reactifiation of vNodes
    this.iApp.children = Object.freeze(this.$slots.default);
  },
  mounted() {
    if (!this.load) this.renderChildren();
  },
  methods: {
    // https://forum.vuejs.org/t/render-inside-iframe/6419/12
    renderChildren() {
      this.load = true;
      const children = this.$slots.default;
      const head = this.$el.contentDocument.head;
      const body = this.$el.contentDocument.body;

      let style = this.$el.contentDocument.createElement("style");
      style.textContent += this.$props.css;
      head.appendChild(style);

      const iApp = new Vue({
        name: "iApp",
        // freezing to prevent unnessessary Reactifiation of vNodes
        data: { children: Object.freeze(children) },
        render(h) {
          return h("body", this.children);
        },
      });

      this.iApp = iApp; // cache instance for later updates
      this.iApp.$mount(body); // mount into iframe
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

***app.vue***

```
<template>
  <Webpage>
    <component :is="name"></component>
  </Webpage>
</template>

<script>
import bloc from "@/components/Bloc";
import Webpage from "@/components/Webpage";
export default {
  components: {
    bloc,
    Webpage,
  },
  computed: {
    name() {
      return "bloc";
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Do you have an idea where this might come from ?

The codesanbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/error-style-component-import-1t1hs?file=/pages/index.vue

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably `Webpage` component overrides it. 
Try moving your style to index and `<Webpage class="bloc">`

Comment: I won't set the style of the bloc component on the webpage component.
I want that his style is appliad on the right component : bloc.